# Flutter:NoSuchMethodError:The method 'Of' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm building a flutter app using VScode.I'm getting an error after the apk gets installed on the emulator but the app fails to start and an error appears on the emulator screen which is the following :

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'Of' was called on null.
Receiver:Null.
Tried calling: of(Instance of 'StatelessElement') 
See also https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors
```

Upon inspection on the console, the following is what is seen:

```html
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies:
[_MyappProvider]):
The method 'of' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: of(Instance of 'StatelessElement')

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MaterialApp
  MaterialApp:file:///C:/App%20Development/MyApp/lib/main.dart:90:16

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      LocalizationService.of (package:Myapp/services/localization.dart:43:49)
#2      _MyAppState.bootstrapMyappProviderInContext (package:Myapp/main.dart:240:51)
#3      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:Myapp/main.dart:150:17)
#4      MaterialPageRoute.buildContent (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:52:55)
#5      MaterialRouteTransitionMixin.buildPage (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:110:27)
#6      _ModalScopeState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:906:55)
#7      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7372:48)
#8      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4949:49)
#9      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
#10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#11     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4859:5)
#12     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
...     Normal element mounting (266 frames)
#278    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#279    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#280    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6447:32)
...     Normal element mounting (155 frames)
#435    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#436    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3586:20)
#437    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#438    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#439    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#440    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
#441    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#442    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#443    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#444    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#445    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:881:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

I/flutter (13116): LateInitializationError: Field '_localizationService@197214030' has not been initialized.
I/flutter (13116): #0      HttpieService._localizationService (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart)
I/flutter (13116): #1      HttpieService._getLanguage (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:359:12)
I/flutter (13116): #2      HttpieService._getHeadersWithConfig (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:373:65)
I/flutter (13116): #3      HttpieService.get (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:223:24)
I/flutter (13116): #4      DocumentsService.getCommunityGuidelines (package:Myapp/services/documents.dart:30:50)
I/flutter (13116): #5      DocumentsService.preload (package:Myapp/services/documents.dart:19:5)
I/flutter (13116): #6      MyappProviderState.initAsyncState (package:Myapp/provider.dart:242:22)
I/flutter (13116): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (13116): In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.
I/flutter (13116): LateInitializationError: Field '_localizationService@197214030' has not been initialized.
I/flutter (13116): #0      HttpieService._localizationService (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart)
I/flutter (13116): #1      HttpieService._getLanguage (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:359:12)
I/flutter (13116): #2      HttpieService._getHeadersWithConfig (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:373:65)
I/flutter (13116): #3      HttpieService.get (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:223:24)
I/flutter (13116): #4      DocumentsService.getPrivacyPolicy (package:Myapp/services/documents.dart:38:50)
I/flutter (13116): #5      DocumentsService.preload (package:Myapp/services/documents.dart:20:5)
I/flutter (13116): #6      MyappProviderState.initAsyncState (package:Myapp/provider.dart:242:22)
I/flutter (13116): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (13116): In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.
I/flutter (13116): LateInitializationError: Field '_localizationService@197214030' has not been initialized.
I/flutter (13116): #0      HttpieService._localizationService (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart)
I/flutter (13116): #1      HttpieService._getLanguage (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:359:12)
I/flutter (13116): #2      HttpieService._getHeadersWithConfig (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:373:65)
I/flutter (13116): #3      HttpieService.get (package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart:223:24)
I/flutter (13116): #4      DocumentsService.getTermsOfUse (package:Myapp/services/documents.dart:46:50)
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

An Observatory debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:60295/QBiGoD5jfGk=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:60299?uri=http://127.0.0.1:60295/QBiGoD5jfGk=/
D/ProfileInstaller(13116): Installing profile for .myapp.app.dev
Application finished.
```

The code that is causing the issue : Main.dart

```html
final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyappProviderKey = GlobalKey<MyappProviderState>();

  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale? newLocale) {
    _MyAppState? state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>();

    state?.setState(() {
      state.locale = newLocale ?? const Locale('en', 'US');
    });
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale? locale;
  late bool _needsBootstrap;

  static const MAX_NETWORK_IMAGE_CACHE_MB = 200;
  static const MAX_NETWORK_IMAGE_CACHE_ENTRIES = 1000;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _needsBootstrap = true;
  }

  void bootstrap() {
    DiskCache().maxEntries = MAX_NETWORK_IMAGE_CACHE_ENTRIES;
    //DiskCache().maxSizeBytes = MAX_NETWORK_IMAGE_CACHE_MB * 1000000; // 200mb
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_needsBootstrap) {
      bootstrap();
      _needsBootstrap = false;
    }

    var textTheme = _defaultTextTheme();
    return MyappProvider(
      key: widget.MyappProviderKey,
      child: OBToast(
        child: MaterialApp(
            navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
            locale: locale,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales) {
              // if no deviceLocale use english
              if (deviceLocale == null) {
                locale = const Locale('en', 'US');
                return locale;
              }
              // initialise locale from device
              if (deviceLocale != null &&
                  supportedLanguages.contains(deviceLocale.languageCode) &&
                  locale == null) {
                Locale supportedMatchedLocale = supportedLocales.firstWhere(
                    (Locale locale) =>
                        locale.languageCode == deviceLocale.languageCode);
                locale = supportedMatchedLocale;
              } else if (locale == null) {
                print(
                    'Locale ${deviceLocale.languageCode} not supported, defaulting to en');
                locale = const Locale('en', 'US');
              }
              return locale;
            },
            title: 'Myapp',
            supportedLocales: supportedLocales,
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              LocalizationServiceDelegate(),
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              MaterialLocalizationPtBRDelegate(),
              CupertinoLocalizationPtBRDelegate(),
              MaterialLocalizationEsESDelegate(),
              CupertinoLocalizationEsESDelegate(),
              MaterialLocalizationSvSEDelegate(),
              CupertinoLocalizationSvSEDelegate(),
            ],
            theme: ThemeData(
                buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0))),
                // This is the theme of your application.
                //
                // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
                // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
                // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
                // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
                // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
                // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
                primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
                fontFamily: 'NunitoSans',
                textTheme: textTheme,
                primaryTextTheme: textTheme),
            routes: {
              /// The MyappProvider uses services available in the context
              /// Their connection must be bootstrapped but no other way to execute
              /// something before loading any route, therefore this ugliness.
              '/': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBHomePage();
              },
              '/auth': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthSplashPage();
              },
              '/auth/token': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthCreateAccountPage();
              },
              '/auth/get-started': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthGetStartedPage();
              },
              '/auth/legal_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBLegalStepPage();
              },
              '/auth/accept_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAcceptStepPage();
              },
              '/auth/name_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthNameStepPage();
              },
              '/auth/email_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthEmailStepPage();
              },
              '/auth/username_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthUsernameStepPage();
              },
              '/auth/password_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthPasswordStepPage();
              },
              '/auth/submit_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthSubmitPage();
              },
              '/auth/done_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthDonePage();
              },
              '/auth/suggested_communities': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBSuggestedCommunitiesPage();
              },
              '/auth/login': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthLoginPage();
              },
              '/auth/forgot_password_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthForgotPasswordPage();
              },
              '/auth/verify_reset_password_link_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthVerifyPasswordPage();
              },
              '/auth/set_new_password_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthSetNewPasswordPage();
              },
              '/auth/password_reset_success_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return const OBAuthPasswordResetSuccessPage();
              },
              '/waitlist/subscribe_email_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                return OBWaitlistSubscribePage();
              },
              '/waitlist/subscribe_done_step': (BuildContext context) {
                bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(context);
                WaitlistSubscribeArguments? args = ModalRoute.of(context)
                    ?.settings
                    .arguments as WaitlistSubscribeArguments?;
                return OBWaitlistSubscribeDoneStep(count: args?.count ?? 0);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  void bootstrapMyappProviderInContext(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    var myappprovider = MyappProvider.of(context);
    var localizationservice = LocalizationService.of(context);
    if (locale?.languageCode != localizationservice.getLocale().languageCode) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0), () {
        MyApp.setLocale(context, locale);
      });
    }
    myappprovider.setLocalizationService(localizationservice);
    UniversalLinksService universalLinksService =
        myappprovider.universalLinksService;
    universalLinksService.digestLinksWithContext(context);
    myappprovider.validationService
        .setLocalizationService(localizationservice);
    myappprovider.shareService.setContext(context);
  }
}

// ignore: prefer_void_to_null
Future<Null> main() async {
  MyApp app = MyApp();

// Run the whole app in a zone to capture all uncaught errors.
  runZonedGuarded(() => runApp(app), (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (isInDebugMode) {
      print(error);
      print(stackTrace);
      print('In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.');
      return;
    }

    SentryClient? sentryClient =
        app.MyappProviderKey.currentState?.sentryClient;

    try {
      sentryClient?.captureException(
        error,
        stackTrace: stackTrace,
      );
      print('Error sent to sentry.io: $error');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Sending report to sentry.io failed: $e');
      print('Original error: $error');
    }
  });
}

bool get isInDebugMode {
  bool inDebugMode = false;
  assert(inDebugMode = true);
  return inDebugMode;
}

bool get isOnDesktop {
  return Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows;
}

TextTheme _defaultTextTheme() {
  // This text theme is merged with the default theme in the `TextData`
  // constructor. This makes sure that the emoji font is used as fallback for
  // every text that uses the default theme.
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var style;
  if (isOnDesktop) {
    style = const TextStyle(fontFamilyFallback: ['Emoji']);
  }
  return TextTheme(
    bodyText2: style,
    bodyText1: style,
    button: style,
    caption: style,
    headline4: style,
    headline3: style,
    headline2: style,
    headline1: style,
    headline5: style,
    overline: style,
    subtitle1: style,
    subtitle2: style,
    headline6: style,
  );
}
```

Kindly assist as i have already spent too much time trying to solve this.

Comment: your code didnt pass `null-safty` .

Comment: @pmatatias, What should be the next step to solve this ?

Comment: as you can see in the logs, there is more than 1 problem. solve it 1 by 1.
starting from issues that have specific messages. example :`Instance of 'StatelessElement'`
in this case, debug your StatelessElement

Comment: One is related to intercom_flutter: i saw that. But I'm unsure how to solve Instance of 'StatelessElement'. I didnt understand what the error means.

Comment: @pmatatias can you help ?. I'm testing this app - https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app

Comment: post the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: @OMiShah. Can you respond. I have updated the code at your request.

Comment: @OMi Shah Have you checked the code

Comment: @Earthling, follow all the steps mentioned here https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app#getting-started Can't tell what exactly is causing the issue. You have to debug yourself after setuping as mentioned in the project's doc.

Comment: Well. I haven't setup the server yet. I believe the app should still fireup to the initial login screen ? which it isn't.

Comment: As an update. I setup the keystore and still the error persists.

Comment: The latest update is the same. Don't know what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the above. For anyone reading this, an incorrectly written variable name(clashing with class definition).

I change a classname in a file call localization.dart which was being refeenced from the above Main.dart.
Any example of what i did:

> var MyProvider = MyProvider.of(context);;

to

> var myprovider = MyProvider.of(context);;

This is i believe to do with Variable name clashing with the Classname.