# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'of' was called on null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, build.gradle

I'm building a flutter app and receiving the following error when i run:

> flutter run --flavor development

The error which shows up is the following:

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'of' was called on null. I dont know if it is related to the exception of Missing plugin bring thrown.

The detailed trace shows the following:

```html
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
myapp.io/receive_share:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel myapp.io/receive_share)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:294:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:637:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8965): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
I/flutter ( 8965): #0      new Environment.fromJson (package:myapp/services/environment_loader.dart:50:34)
I/flutter ( 8965): #1      EnvironmentLoader.load.<anonymous closure> (package:myapp/services/environment_loader.dart:13:45)
I/flutter ( 8965): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1399:47)
I/flutter ( 8965): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1300:19)
I/flutter ( 8965): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 8965): In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.
I/flutter ( 8965): Clearing prompted user for permission
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9106?uri=http://127.0.0.1:59439/1DkvGghzJD8=/
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please call Intercom.initialize() before requesting the client.
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at io.intercom.android.sdk.Intercom$Companion.client(Intercom.kt:622)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at io.maido.intercom.IntercomFlutterPlugin.onMethodCall(IntercomFlutterPlugin.kt:130)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#maido.io/intercom( 8965):       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
I/flutter ( 8965): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 8965): #1      KNHomePageState._logout (package:myapp/pages/home/home.dart:340:7)I/flutter ( 8965): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 8965): In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.
```

httpie.dart

```html
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:myapp/services/localization.dart';
import 'package:myapp/services/utils_service.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';
import 'package:http_retry/http_retry.dart';
export 'package:http/http.dart';

class HttpieService {
  late LocalizationService _localizationService;
  late UtilsService _utilsService;
  String? authorizationToken;
  String? magicHeaderName;
  String? magicHeaderValue;
  late Client client;

  HttpieService() {
    client = IOClient();
    client = RetryClient(client,
        when: _retryWhenResponse, whenError: _retryWhenError);
  }

  bool _retryWhenResponse(BaseResponse response) {
    return response.statusCode >= 503 && response.statusCode < 600;
  }

  bool _retryWhenError(error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    return error is SocketException || error is ClientException;
  }

  void setAuthorizationToken(String token) {
    authorizationToken = token;
  }

  String? getAuthorizationToken() {
    return authorizationToken;
  }

  void removeAuthorizationToken() {
    authorizationToken = null;
  }

  void setLocalizationService(LocalizationService localizationService) {
    _localizationService = localizationService;
  }

  void setUtilsService(UtilsService utilsService) {
    _utilsService = utilsService;
  }

  void setMagicHeader(String name, String value) {
    magicHeaderName = name;
    magicHeaderValue = value;
  }

  void setProxy(String proxy) {
    var overrides = HttpOverrides.current as HttpieOverrides?;
    if (overrides != null) {
      overrides.setProxy(proxy);
    }
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> post(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) async {
    var finalHeaders = _getHeadersWithConfig(
        headers: headers,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);

    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await client.post(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: finalHeaders, body: body, encoding: encoding);
    } catch (error) {
      _handleRequestError(error);
    }

    return HttpieResponse(response);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> put(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) async {
    var finalHeaders = _getHeadersWithConfig(
        headers: headers,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);

    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await client.put(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: finalHeaders, body: body, encoding: encoding);
    } catch (error) {
      _handleRequestError(error);
    }
    return HttpieResponse(response);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> patch(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) async {
    var finalHeaders = _getHeadersWithConfig(
        headers: headers,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);

    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await client.patch(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: finalHeaders, body: body, encoding: encoding);
    } catch (error) {
      _handleRequestError(error);
    }

    return HttpieResponse(response);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> delete(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) async {
    var finalHeaders = _getHeadersWithConfig(
        headers: headers,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);

    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await client.delete(Uri.parse(url), headers: finalHeaders);
    } catch (error) {
      _handleRequestError(error);
    }

    return HttpieResponse(response);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> postJSON(url,
      {Map<String, String> headers = const {},
      body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    String jsonBody = json.encode(body);

    Map<String, String> jsonHeaders = _getJsonHeaders();

    jsonHeaders.addAll(headers);

    return post(url,
        headers: jsonHeaders,
        body: jsonBody,
        encoding: encoding,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> putJSON(url,
      {Map<String, String> headers = const {},
      body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    String jsonBody = json.encode(body);

    Map<String, String> jsonHeaders = _getJsonHeaders();

    jsonHeaders.addAll(headers);

    return put(url,
        headers: jsonHeaders,
        body: jsonBody,
        encoding: encoding,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> patchJSON(url,
      {Map<String, String> headers = const {},
      body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    String jsonBody = json.encode(body);

    Map<String, String> jsonHeaders = _getJsonHeaders();

    jsonHeaders.addAll(headers);

    return patch(url,
        headers: jsonHeaders,
        body: jsonBody,
        encoding: encoding,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> get(url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) async {
    var finalHeaders = _getHeadersWithConfig(
        headers: headers,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);

    // ignore: prefer_is_empty
    if (queryParameters != null && queryParameters.keys.length > 0) {
      url = url + _makeQueryString(queryParameters);
    }

    Response? response;

    try {
      response = await client.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: finalHeaders);
    } catch (error) {
      _handleRequestError(error);
    }

    return HttpieResponse(response);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> postMultiform(String url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      Map<String, dynamic>? body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    return _multipartRequest(url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        encoding: encoding,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> patchMultiform(String url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      Map<String, dynamic>? body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    return _multipartRequest(url,
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        encoding: encoding,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> putMultiform(String url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      Map<String, dynamic>? body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    return _multipartRequest(url,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: headers,
        body: body,
        encoding: encoding,
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> _multipartRequest(String url,
      {Map<String, String>? headers,
      required String method,
      Map<String, dynamic>? body,
      Encoding? encoding,
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(method, Uri.parse(url));

    var finalHeaders = _getHeadersWithConfig(
        headers: headers ?? {},
        appendLanguageHeader: appendLanguageHeader,
        appendAuthorizationToken: appendAuthorizationToken);

    request.headers.addAll(finalHeaders);

    List<Future> fileFields = [];

    List<String>? bodyKeys = body?.keys.toList();

    if (bodyKeys != null) {
      for (final String key in bodyKeys) {
        dynamic value = body![key];
        if (value is String || value is bool) {
          request.fields[key] = value.toString();
        } else if (value is List) {
          request.fields[key] =
              value.map((item) => item.toString()).toList().join(',');
        } else if (value is File) {
          String fileMimeType = await _utilsService.getFileMimeType(value);

          String? fileExtension =
              _utilsService.getFileExtensionForMimeType(fileMimeType);

          var bytes = utf8.encode(value.path);
          var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);

          String newFileName = fileExtension == null
              ? digest.toString()
              : '$digest.$fileExtension';

          MediaType fileMediaType = MediaType.parse(fileMimeType);

          var fileFuture = http.MultipartFile.fromPath(key, value.path,
              filename: newFileName, contentType: fileMediaType);

          fileFields.add(fileFuture);
        } else {
          throw const HttpieArgumentsError('Unsupported multiform value type');
        }
      }
    }

    var files = await Future.wait(fileFields);
    // ignore: avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls
    files.forEach((file) => request.files.add(file));

    // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
    var response;

    try {
      response = await client.send(request);
    } catch (error) {
      _handleRequestError(error);
    }

    return HttpieStreamedResponse(response);
  }

  String _getLanguage() {
    return _localizationService.getLocale().languageCode.toLowerCase();
  }

  Map<String, String> _getHeadersWithConfig(
      {Map<String, String>? headers = const {},
      bool? appendLanguageHeader,
      bool? appendAuthorizationToken}) {
    headers = headers ?? {};

    Map<String, String> finalHeaders = Map.from(headers);

    appendLanguageHeader = appendLanguageHeader ?? true;
    appendAuthorizationToken = appendAuthorizationToken ?? false;

    if (appendLanguageHeader) finalHeaders['Accept-Language'] = _getLanguage();

    if (appendAuthorizationToken && authorizationToken != null) {
      finalHeaders['Authorization'] = 'Token $authorizationToken';
    }

    if (magicHeaderName != null && magicHeaderValue != null) {
      finalHeaders[magicHeaderName!] = magicHeaderValue!;
    }

    return finalHeaders;
  }

  void _handleRequestError(error) {
    if (error is SocketException) {
      var errorCode = error.osError?.errorCode;
      if (errorCode == 61 ||
          errorCode == 60 ||
          errorCode == 111 ||
          // Network is unreachable
          errorCode == 101 ||
          errorCode == 104 ||
          errorCode == 51 ||
          errorCode == 8 ||
          errorCode == 113 ||
          errorCode == 7 ||
          errorCode == 64) {
        // Connection refused.
        throw HttpieConnectionRefusedError(error);
      }
    }

    throw error;
  }

  Map<String, String> _getJsonHeaders() {
    return {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
  }

  String _makeQueryString(Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters) {
    String queryString = '?';
    queryParameters.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value != null) {
        queryString += '$key=' + _stringifyQueryStringValue(value) + '&';
      }
    });
    return queryString;
  }

  String _stringifyQueryStringValue(dynamic value) {
    if (value is String) return value;
    if (value is bool || value is int || value is double) {
      return value.toString();
    }
    if (value is List) {
      return value
          .map((valueItem) => _stringifyQueryStringValue(valueItem))
          .join(',');
    }
    throw 'Unsupported query string value';
  }
}

abstract class HttpieBaseResponse<T extends http.BaseResponse> {
  final T _httpResponse;

  HttpieBaseResponse(this._httpResponse);

  bool isInternalServerError() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.internalServerError;
  }

  bool isBadRequest() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.badRequest;
  }

  bool isOk() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok;
  }

  bool isUnauthorized() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.unauthorized;
  }

  bool isForbidden() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.forbidden;
  }

  bool isAccepted() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.accepted;
  }

  bool isCreated() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.created;
  }

  bool isNotFound() {
    return _httpResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.notFound;
  }

  int get statusCode => _httpResponse.statusCode;
}

class HttpieResponse extends HttpieBaseResponse<http.Response> {
  // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
  HttpieResponse(_httpResponse) : super(_httpResponse);

  String get body {
    return utf8.decode(_httpResponse.bodyBytes);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> parseJsonBody() {
    return json.decode(body);
  }

  http.Response get httpResponse => _httpResponse;
}

class HttpieStreamedResponse extends HttpieBaseResponse<http.StreamedResponse> {
  // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
  HttpieStreamedResponse(_httpResponse) : super(_httpResponse);

  Future<String> readAsString() {
    var completer = Completer<String>();
    var contents = StringBuffer();
    _httpResponse.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((String data) {
      contents.write(data);
    }, onDone: () {
      completer.complete(contents.toString());
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
}

class HttpieRequestError<T extends HttpieBaseResponse> implements Exception {
  static String convertStatusCodeToHumanReadableMessage(int statusCode) {
    String readableMessage;

    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.notFound) {
      readableMessage = 'Not found';
    } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.forbidden) {
      readableMessage = 'You are not allowed to do this';
    } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.badRequest) {
      readableMessage = 'Bad request';
    } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.internalServerError) {
      readableMessage =
          'We\'re experiencing server errors. Please try again later.';
    } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.serviceUnavailable ||
        statusCode == HttpStatus.serviceUnavailable) {
      readableMessage =
          'We\'re experiencing server errors. Please try again later.';
    } else {
      readableMessage = 'Server error';
    }

    return readableMessage;
  }

  final T response;

  const HttpieRequestError(this.response);

  @override
  String toString() {
    String statusCode = response.statusCode.toString();
    String stringifiedError = 'HttpieRequestError:$statusCode';

    if (response is HttpieResponse) {
      var castedResponse = response as HttpieResponse;
      stringifiedError = '$stringifiedError | ${castedResponse.body}';
    }

    return stringifiedError;
  }

  Future<String> body() async {
    late String body;

    if (response is HttpieResponse) {
      HttpieResponse castedResponse = response as HttpieResponse;
      body = castedResponse.body;
    } else if (response is HttpieStreamedResponse) {
      HttpieStreamedResponse castedResponse =
          response as HttpieStreamedResponse;
      body = await castedResponse.readAsString();
    }
    return body;
  }

  Future<String?> toHumanReadableMessage() async {
    String errorBody = await body();

    try {
      dynamic parsedError = json.decode(errorBody);
      if (parsedError is Map) {
        if (parsedError.isNotEmpty) {
          if (parsedError.containsKey('detail')) {
            return parsedError['detail'];
          } else if (parsedError.containsKey('message')) {
            return parsedError['message'];
          } else {
            dynamic mapFirstValue = parsedError.values.toList().first;
            dynamic value = mapFirstValue is List ? mapFirstValue[0] : null;
            if (value != null && value is String) {
              return value;
            } else {
              return convertStatusCodeToHumanReadableMessage(
                  response.statusCode);
            }
          }
        } else {
          return convertStatusCodeToHumanReadableMessage(response.statusCode);
        }
      } else if (parsedError is List && parsedError.isNotEmpty) {
        return parsedError.first;
      }

      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      return convertStatusCodeToHumanReadableMessage(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}

class HttpieConnectionRefusedError implements Exception {
  final SocketException socketException;

  const HttpieConnectionRefusedError(this.socketException);

  @override
  String toString() {
    String address = socketException.address.toString();
    String port = socketException.port.toString();
    return 'HttpieConnectionRefusedError: Connection refused on $address and port $port';
  }

  String toHumanReadableMessage() {
    return 'No internet connection.';
  }
}

class HttpieArgumentsError implements Exception {
  final String msg;

  const HttpieArgumentsError(this.msg);

  @override
  String toString() => 'HttpieArgumentsError: $msg';
}

// These overrides are used by the standard dart:http/HttpClient to change how
// it behaves. All settings changed here will apply to every single HttpClient
// used by any other package, as long as they're running inside a zone with
// these set.
class HttpieOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  String? _proxy;
  final HttpOverrides? _previous = HttpOverrides.current;

  HttpieOverrides();

  void setProxy(String proxy) {
    _proxy = proxy;
  }

  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    if (_previous != null) return _previous!.createHttpClient(context);
    return super.createHttpClient(context);
  }

  @override
  String findProxyFromEnvironment(Uri uri, Map<String, String>? environment) {
    if (_proxy != null) return _proxy!;
    if (_previous != null) {
      return _previous!.findProxyFromEnvironment(uri, environment);
    }
    return super.findProxyFromEnvironment(uri, environment);
  }
}
```

I'm unable to solve the above and spent quite a while on the above. Kindly help.

Comment: From the trace you shared, it looks like that the request cannot be made since the url can't be parsed. But this seems not connected to the build error in my opintion.

Comment: Its an open source app which has its own api to be installed separately(which i have on gcp). Could this be related to no response being received from server end. This is the repo im using https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app

Comment: Also Stefan, I had NoSuchMethodError earlier too related to something else too which i solved by correcting the classname which was incorrectly not referencing the said import package. I went to trace it though similar logs above and found the culprit in this case. Here is the question i posted earlier which i have solved just a few hours back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284254/flutternosuchmethoderrorthe-method-of-was-called-on-null?noredirect=1#comment131195040_74284254

Comment: @Stefan. Had mistakenly missed an important trace which i have updated. Could you please check ?

Comment: By the way, why do you run with `--no-sound-null-safety`? Perhaps if you enable it again the static analysis will point out a problem with `null`s. Also it seems the `url` parameter in `HttpieService.get` doesn't have a specified type. The problem might be that this `url` is null when passed to `client.get`.

Comment: @Anakhand. There are 2 plugins in pubspec.yaml currently do not support null safety. Also, i have deployed the backend server django api on port 80 and the admin is showing up. I cant understand why the app isnt able to connect. I'm using the following stack https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app and https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-api

Comment: I migrated to null safety by replacing a plugin and updating the other. Here is the error which shows when i  input username and password : LateInitializationError: Field 'apiURL' has not been initialized.

Comment: Hi again. Here is a separate question linked to this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74475116/lateinitializationerror-field-apiurl-has-not-been-initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From intercom_flutter usage (https://pub.dev/packages/intercom_flutter#usage)

> // make sure to add keys from your Intercom workspace.
> `await Intercom.instance.initialize('appIdHere', iosApiKey: 'iosKeyHere', androidApiKey: 'androidKeyHere');`

I think you have missed this as it is evident from the stacktrace your shared.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please call Intercom.initialize() before requesting the client.`

Comment: Hi @Rahul. The Late Initialization error for apiURL - i have posted a separate question and removed it from here. Could you look into it ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74475116/lateinitializationerror-field-apiurl-has-not-been-initialized