# LateInitializationError: Field 'apiURL' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting he following error when I'm trying to connect to my backend api deployed on GCP.

**LateInitializationError: Field 'apiURL' has not been initialized**

The trace shows the following :

```html
I/flutter (20883): LateInitializationError: Field 'apiURL' has not been initialized.
I/flutter (20883): #0      AuthApiService.apiURL (package:Myapp/services/auth_api.dart)
I/flutter (20883): #1      AuthApiService.loginWithCredentials (package:Myapp/services/auth_api.dart:335:41)
I/flutter (20883): #2      UserService.loginWithCredentials (package:Myapp/services/user.dart:338:53)
I/flutter (20883): #3      KNAuthLoginPageState._login (package:Myapp/pages/auth/login.dart:145:26)
I/flutter (20883): #4      KNAuthLoginPageState._submitForm (package:Myapp/pages/auth/login.dart:136:13)
I/flutter (20883): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
I/flutter (20883): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
I/flutter (20883): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
I/flutter (20883): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239:7)
I/flutter (20883): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:615:9)
I/flutter (20883): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
I/flutter (20883): #11     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
I/flutter (20883): In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.
```

My auth_api.dart :

```html
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:Myapp/models/language.dart';
import 'package:Myapp/services/httpie.dart';
import 'package:Myapp/services/string_template.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class AuthApiService {
  late HttpieService _httpService;
  late StringTemplateService _stringTemplateService;

  late String apiURL;

  static const CHECK_USERNAME_PATH = 'api/auth/username-check/';
  static const CHECK_EMAIL_PATH = 'api/auth/email-check/';
  static const UPDATE_EMAIL_PATH = 'api/auth/user/settings/';
  static const VERIFY_EMAIL_TOKEN = 'api/auth/email/verify/';
  static const ACCEPT_GUIDELINES = 'api/auth/user/accept-guidelines/';
  static const SET_NEW_LANGUAGE = 'api/auth/user/languages/';
  static const GET_NEW_LANGUAGE = 'api/auth/user/languages/';
  static const UPDATE_PASSWORD_PATH = 'api/auth/user/settings/';
  static const CREATE_ACCOUNT_PATH = 'api/auth/register/';
  static const VERIFY_REGISTER_TOKEN = 'api/auth/register/verify-token/';
  static const DELETE_ACCOUNT_PATH = 'api/auth/user/delete/';
  static const GET_AUTHENTICATED_USER_PATH = 'api/auth/user/';
  static const UPDATE_AUTHENTICATED_USER_PATH = 'api/auth/user/';
  static const GET_USERS_PATH = 'api/auth/users/';
  static const REPORT_USER_PATH = 'api/auth/users/{userUsername}/report/';
  static const GET_LINKED_USERS_PATH = 'api/auth/linked-users/';
  static const SEARCH_LINKED_USERS_PATH = 'api/auth/linked-users/search/';
  static const GET_BLOCKED_USERS_PATH = 'api/auth/blocked-users/';
  static const SEARCH_BLOCKED_USERS_PATH = 'api/auth/blocked-users/search/';
  static const ENABLE_NEW_POST_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR_USER_PATH =
      'api/auth/users/{userUsername}/notifications/subscribe/new-post/';
  static const BLOCK_USER_PATH = 'api/auth/users/{userUsername}/block/';
  static const UNBLOCK_USER_PATH = 'api/auth/users/{userUsername}/unblock/';
  static const GET_FOLLOWERS_PATH = 'api/auth/followers/';
  static const SEARCH_FOLLOWERS_PATH = 'api/auth/followers/search/';
  static const GET_FOLLOWINGS_PATH = 'api/auth/followings/';
  static const SEARCH_FOLLOWINGS_PATH = 'api/auth/followings/search/';
  static const LOGIN_PATH = 'api/auth/login/';
  static const REQUEST_RESET_PASSWORD_PATH = 'api/auth/password/reset/';
  static const VERIFY_RESET_PASSWORD_PATH = 'api/auth/password/verify/';
  static const AUTHENTICATED_USER_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS_PATH =
      'api/auth/user/notifications-settings/';

  void setHttpService(HttpieService httpService) {
    _httpService = httpService;
  }

  void setStringTemplateService(StringTemplateService stringTemplateService) {
    _stringTemplateService = stringTemplateService;
  }

  void setApiURL(String newApiURL) {
    apiURL = newApiURL;
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> deleteUser({required String password}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'password': password};
    return _httpService.post('$apiURL$DELETE_ACCOUNT_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> checkUsernameIsAvailable({required String username}) {
    return _httpService
        .postJSON('$apiURL$CHECK_USERNAME_PATH', body: {'username': username});
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> checkEmailIsAvailable({required String email}) {
    return _httpService
        .postJSON('$apiURL$CHECK_EMAIL_PATH', body: {'email': email});
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> updateUserEmail({required String email}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {};
    body['email'] = email;
    return _httpService.patchMultiform('$apiURL$UPDATE_EMAIL_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> updateUserPassword(
      {required String currentPassword, required String newPassword}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {};
    body['current_password'] = currentPassword;
    body['new_password'] = newPassword;
    return _httpService.patchMultiform('$apiURL$UPDATE_PASSWORD_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> verifyEmailWithToken(String token) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'token': token};
    return _httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$VERIFY_EMAIL_TOKEN',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> updateUser({
    dynamic avatar,
    dynamic cover,
    String? name,
    String? username,
    String? url,
    bool? followersCountVisible,
    bool? communityPostsVisible,
    String? bio,
    String? location,
    String? visibility,
  }) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {};

    if (avatar is File) {
      body['avatar'] = avatar;
    } else if (avatar is String && avatar.isEmpty) {
      // This is what deletes the avatar. Ugly af.
      body['avatar'] = avatar;
    }

    if (cover is File) {
      body['cover'] = cover;
    } else if (cover is String && cover.isEmpty) {
      // This is what deletes the cover. Ugly af.
      body['cover'] = cover;
    }

    if (name != null) body['name'] = name;

    if (username != null) body['username'] = username;

    if (url != null) body['url'] = url;

    if (bio != null) body['bio'] = bio;

    if (visibility != null) body['visibility'] = visibility;

    if (followersCountVisible != null)
      body['followers_count_visible'] = followersCountVisible;

    if (communityPostsVisible != null)
      body['community_posts_visible'] = communityPostsVisible;

    if (location != null) body['location'] = location;

    return _httpService.patchMultiform('$apiURL$UPDATE_AUTHENTICATED_USER_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieStreamedResponse> createUser(
      {required String email,
      required String token,
      required String name,
      required String username,
      required bool isOfLegalAge,
      required bool areGuidelinesAccepted,
      required String password,
      File? avatar}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'email': email,
      'token': token,
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'is_of_legal_age': isOfLegalAge,
      'are_guidelines_accepted': areGuidelinesAccepted,
      'password': password
    };

    if (avatar != null) {
      body['avatar'] = avatar;
    }

    return _httpService.postMultiform('$apiURL$CREATE_ACCOUNT_PATH',
        body: body);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> verifyRegisterToken({required String token}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'token': token};

    return _httpService.post('$apiURL$VERIFY_REGISTER_TOKEN', body: body);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getUserWithAuthToken(String authToken) {
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Authorization': 'Token $authToken'};

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_AUTHENTICATED_USER_PATH',
        headers: headers);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getUserWithUsername(String username,
      {bool authenticatedRequest = true}) {
    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_USERS_PATH$username/',
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getPostsCountForUserWithName(String username,
      {bool authenticatedRequest = true}) {
    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_USERS_PATH$username/posts/count/',
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getUsersWithQuery(String query,
      {bool authenticatedRequest = true}) {
    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_USERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: {'query': query},
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> searchLinkedUsers(
      {required String query, int? count, String? withCommunity}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {'query': query};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    if (withCommunity != null) queryParams['with_community'] = withCommunity;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$SEARCH_LINKED_USERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getLinkedUsers(
      {bool authenticatedRequest = true,
      int? maxId,
      int? count,
      String? withCommunity}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    if (maxId != null) queryParams['max_id'] = maxId;

    if (withCommunity != null) queryParams['with_community'] = withCommunity;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_LINKED_USERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> searchBlockedUsers(
      {required String query, int? count}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {'query': query};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$SEARCH_BLOCKED_USERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getBlockedUsers({
    bool authenticatedRequest = true,
    int? maxId,
    int? count,
  }) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    if (maxId != null) queryParams['max_id'] = maxId;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_BLOCKED_USERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> blockUserWithUsername(String userUsername) {
    String path = _makeBlockUserWithUsernamePath(userUsername);
    return _httpService.post(_makeApiUrl(path), appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> unblockUserWithUsername(String userUsername) {
    String path = _makeUnblockUserWithUsernamePath(userUsername);
    return _httpService.post(_makeApiUrl(path), appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> enableNewPostNotificationsForUserWithUsername(
      String userUsername) {
    String path =
        _makeEnableNewPostNotificationsForUserWithUsernamePath(userUsername);
    return _httpService.putJSON(_makeApiUrl(path),
        appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> disableNewPostNotificationsForUserWithUsername(
      String userUsername) {
    String path =
        _makeEnableNewPostNotificationsForUserWithUsernamePath(userUsername);
    return _httpService.delete(_makeApiUrl(path),
        appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> searchFollowers({required String query, int? count}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {'query': query};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$SEARCH_FOLLOWERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getFollowers(
      {bool authenticatedRequest = true, int? maxId, int? count}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    if (maxId != null) queryParams['max_id'] = maxId;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_FOLLOWERS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> searchFollowings({required String query, int? count}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {'query': query};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$SEARCH_FOLLOWINGS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getFollowings({
    bool authenticatedRequest = true,
    int? maxId,
    int? count,
  }) {
    Map<String, dynamic> queryParams = {};

    if (count != null) queryParams['count'] = count;

    if (maxId != null) queryParams['max_id'] = maxId;

    return _httpService.get('$apiURL$GET_FOLLOWINGS_PATH',
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        appendAuthorizationToken: authenticatedRequest);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> loginWithCredentials(
      {required String username, required String password}) {
    return this._httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$LOGIN_PATH',
        body: {'username': username, 'password': password});
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> requestPasswordReset({required String email}) {
    var body = {};
    if (email != null && email != '') {
      body['email'] = email;
    }
    return this
        ._httpService
        .postJSON('$apiURL$REQUEST_RESET_PASSWORD_PATH', body: body);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> verifyPasswordReset(
      {String? newPassword, String? passwordResetToken}) {
    return this._httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$VERIFY_RESET_PASSWORD_PATH',
        body: {'new_password': newPassword, 'token': passwordResetToken});
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getAuthenticatedUserNotificationsSettings() {
    return this._httpService.get(
        '$apiURL$AUTHENTICATED_USER_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS_PATH',
        appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> updateAuthenticatedUserNotificationsSettings({
    bool? postCommentNotifications,
    bool? postCommentReplyNotifications,
    bool? postCommentReactionNotifications,
    bool? postCommentUserMentionNotifications,
    bool? postUserMentionNotifications,
    bool? postReactionNotifications,
    bool? followNotifications,
    bool? followRequestNotifications,
    bool? followRequestApprovedNotifications,
    bool? connectionRequestNotifications,
    bool? connectionConfirmedNotifications,
    bool? communityInviteNotifications,
    bool? communityNewPostNotifications,
    bool? userNewPostNotifications,
  }) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {};

    if (postCommentNotifications != null)
      body['post_comment_notifications'] = postCommentNotifications;

    if (postCommentReplyNotifications != null)
      body['post_comment_reply_notifications'] = postCommentReplyNotifications;

    if (postCommentUserMentionNotifications != null)
      body['post_comment_user_mention_notifications'] =
          postCommentUserMentionNotifications;

    if (postUserMentionNotifications != null)
      body['post_user_mention_notifications'] = postUserMentionNotifications;

    if (postCommentReactionNotifications != null)
      body['post_comment_reaction_notifications'] =
          postCommentReactionNotifications;

    if (postReactionNotifications != null)
      body['post_reaction_notifications'] = postReactionNotifications;

    if (followNotifications != null)
      body['follow_notifications'] = followNotifications;

    if (followRequestNotifications != null)
      body['follow_request_notifications'] = followRequestNotifications;

    if (followRequestApprovedNotifications != null)
      body['follow_request_approved_notifications'] =
          followRequestApprovedNotifications;

    if (connectionRequestNotifications != null)
      body['connection_request_notifications'] = connectionRequestNotifications;

    if (communityInviteNotifications != null)
      body['community_invite_notifications'] = communityInviteNotifications;

    if (communityNewPostNotifications != null)
      body['community_new_post_notifications'] = communityNewPostNotifications;

    if (userNewPostNotifications != null)
      body['user_new_post_notifications'] = userNewPostNotifications;

    if (connectionConfirmedNotifications != null)
      body['connection_confirmed_notifications'] =
          connectionConfirmedNotifications;

    return _httpService.patchJSON(
        '$apiURL$AUTHENTICATED_USER_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS_PATH',
        body: body,
        appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> acceptGuidelines() {
    return this
        ._httpService
        .post('$apiURL$ACCEPT_GUIDELINES', appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> getAllLanguages() {
    String url = _makeApiUrl(GET_NEW_LANGUAGE);
    return _httpService.get(url, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> setNewLanguage(Language language) {
    Map<String, String> body = {'language_id': language.id.toString()};
    return this._httpService.post('$apiURL$SET_NEW_LANGUAGE',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> reportUserWithUsername(
      {required String userUsername,
      required int moderationCategoryId,
      String? description}) {
    String path = _makeReportUserPath(username: userUsername);

    Map<String, String> body = {'category_id': moderationCategoryId.toString()};

    if (description != null && description.isNotEmpty) {
      body['description'] = description;
    }

    return _httpService.post(_makeApiUrl(path),
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  String _makeBlockUserWithUsernamePath(String username) {
    return _stringTemplateService
        .parse(BLOCK_USER_PATH, {'userUsername': username});
  }

  String _makeUnblockUserWithUsernamePath(String username) {
    return _stringTemplateService
        .parse(UNBLOCK_USER_PATH, {'userUsername': username});
  }

  String _makeEnableNewPostNotificationsForUserWithUsernamePath(
      String username) {
    return _stringTemplateService.parse(
        ENABLE_NEW_POST_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR_USER_PATH,
        {'userUsername': username});
  }

  String _makeReportUserPath({required username}) {
    return _stringTemplateService
        .parse(REPORT_USER_PATH, {'userUsername': username});
  }

  String _makeApiUrl(String string) {
    return '$apiURL$string';
  }
}
```

The setApiURL is used in the following provider.dart:

```html
authApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    postsApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    emojisApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    userInvitesApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    followsApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    moderationApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    connectionsApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    connectionsCirclesApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    followsListsApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    communitiesApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    hashtagsApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    categoriesApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    notificationsApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    devicesApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl);
    waitlistApiService
        .setMyAppApiURL(environment.MyAppApiUrl);
```

Edit :
I did the following changes as recommended as recommended in the comments. In provider.dart, where setApiURL is called :

```html
authApiService.apiURL = ''; // Initialized apiURl(auth_api.dart) as empty String & Called authApiService(auth_api.dart) which contains the function setapiUrl
if (authApiService.apiURL.isEmpty) { authApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl)};//Set a condition before using the apiUrl.

The above has no effect.
```

I then tried the following :

```html
auth_api.dart
String? apiURL;
void setApiURL(String newApiURL) { if (apiURL == null) { apiURL = newApiURL; } } 

The error now changes to Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI nullapi/auth/login/

I reverted to original keeping only 

String? apiURL;

and change the following in provider.dart

if (authApiService.apiURL == null) { authApiService.setApiURL(environment.apiUrl)}.

The error remians to to Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI nullapi/auth/login/
```

Based on Mohan's request, i have updated the following :

```html
user_invite.dart

static const  INVITE_LINK = '{apiURL}api/auth/invite?token={token}';

user_invite_detail.dart

String inviteLink = _stringTemplateService.parse(UserInvite.INVITE_LINK, {'token': token, 'apiURL': apiURL});

List<Widget> _buildActionsList() {
    if (widget.userInvite.createdUser != null) {
      return [const SizedBox()];
    }

    return [
      ListTile(
        leading: const KNIcon(KNIcons.chat),
        title: KNText(_localizationService.user__invites_share_yourself),
        subtitle: KNSecondaryText(
          _localizationService.user__invites_share_yourself_desc,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          String? apiURL = _userInvitesApiService.apiURL;
          String token = widget.userInvite.token!;
          Share.share(getShareMessageForInviteWithToken(token, apiURL));
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const KNIcon(KNIcons.email),
        title: KNText(_localizationService.user__invites_share_email),
        subtitle: KNSecondaryText(
          _localizationService.user__invites_share_email_desc,
        ),
        onTap: () async {
          await _modalService.openSendUserInviteEmail(
              context: context, userInvite: widget.userInvite);
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      )
    ];
  }
  
  
  There are other files with this format like in connection_dart below:
  
  String?apiURL;
  
  void setApiURL(String newApiURL) {
    apiURL = newApiURL;
  }
  
  Future<HttpieResponse> connectWithUserWithUsername(String username,
      {List<int>? circlesIds}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'username': username};

    if (circlesIds != null) body['circles_ids'] = circlesIds;

    return _httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$CONNECT_WITH_USER_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }
  
  Future<HttpieResponse> confirmConnectionWithUserWithUsername(String username,
      {List<int>? circlesIds}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'username': username};

    if (circlesIds != null) body['circles_ids'] = circlesIds;

    return _httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$CONFIRM_CONNECTION_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> disconnectFromUserWithUsername(String username) {
    return _httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$DISCONNECT_FROM_USER_PATH',
        body: {'username': username}, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }

  Future<HttpieResponse> updateConnectionWithUsername(String username,
      {List<int>? circlesIds}) {
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'username': username};

    if (circlesIds != null) body['circles_ids'] = circlesIds;

    return _httpService.postJSON('$apiURL$UPDATE_CONNECTION_PATH',
        body: body, appendAuthorizationToken: true);
  }
}
```

Comment: where you are calling `setApiURL`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh updated question with your request

Comment: For more information: This is the stack i'm using https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app. Files to be looked at : provider.dart. environment_loader.dart and auth_api.dart

Comment: hard to predict for me, you can try providing empty string and do a empty check, like `String apiURL="";` then check `if()apiURL.isEmpty` while using it

Comment: ok. Also my site doesnt have ssl. could that be the reason ?

Comment: Sorry dont know about that

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: The error message says, `apiURL` property is declared as `late` but it is being used before being initialised. You need to initialise it by calling `setApiURL`  as @YeasinSheikh suggested. Also, make sure you aren't creating different object of your authApiService in case of login as provider sets property to only one instance which was available there.

Answer (score 0):

`LateInitializationError: Field 'apiURL' has not been initialized`

It means the `apiURL` is not yet initiated at the moment where it is getting used.

So make sure you are initialising the `apiURL` before it is getting used
or if you are not sure then change  `late String apiURL;` to `String? apiURL;` and add null checks while using it.

By making `apiURL` nullable we are telling the compiler that it can be a null value.

Comment: @Earthling Please update the question with latest error log, So that I can better understand the issue

Comment: @Earthling it happens because, you're still calling apiURL somewhere in the UI even before it gets assigned the valid value, thus it gives an invalid URL with a null value. Please check your UI logic code or update that in the question

Comment: Hi Mohan. Updated. Pls check.

Comment: Hello Mohan. Checked ?

Comment: @Earthling It's not sure, where you're calling INVITE_LINK. that's what causing the issue I believe, If you want we can hop on a call or something.

Comment: Hi Mohan. Sure. Ill add you on LinkedIn and message you. Meanwhile the question you asked: I have updated the question with details.

Comment: Im  testing this open source stack:https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app