# error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. Error

Tags: flutter

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:ftmovie/src/data/core/api_constants.dart';
import 'package:ftmovie/src/data/models/movie_model.dart';
import 'package:ftmovie/src/data/models/movies_result_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

abstract class MovieRemoteDataSource {
  Future<List<MovieModel>> getTrending();
}

class MovieRemoteDataSourceImpl extends MovieRemoteDataSource {
  final Client _client;

  MovieRemoteDataSourceImpl(this._client);

  @override
  Future<List<MovieModel>> getTrending() async {
    final response = await _client.get(
      '${ApiConstants.BASE_URL}trending/movie/day?api_key=${ApiConstants.API_KEY}',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
      final movies = MoviesResultModel.fromJson(responseBody).movies;
      print(movies);
      return movies;
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

The part where I get the error: '${ApiConstants.BASE_URL}trending/movie/day?api_key=${ApiConstants.API_KEY}', where the code is. I would appreciate your help.

I also asked my friends who know a little flutter. I tried everything they wrote on the internet, but I can't print and see the data in any way.

Answer (score 0):

`get` takes an `Uri` object, not a `String`. Fortunately it's very easy to convert. Just write

```
final response = await _client.get(
  Uri.parse('${ApiConstants.BASE_URL}trending/movie/day?api_key=${ApiConstants.API_KEY}'),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
);
```

Comment: I did as you said but it gave me this output. 

'
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
'

Comment: @Koray That's probably in another part of your code. I'm guessing in the `MoviesResultModel.fromJson` part. Probably you try to get a field that you indicated is a String but actually returned null from the api

Comment: '
MoviesResultModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    movies = List.from(json['results']).map((e)=>MovieModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
'

I wonder if this is the code place you're talking about?

Comment: @Koray then I would think in the `MovieModel` actually but it's really hard to tell without seeing the full code and also the full response of your api

Comment: How can I throw you all the codes?

Comment: I think you have the same issue as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74542643/fluttertype-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-in-type-cast . Like the mistake they had in their `Environment` you most likely have in `MovieModel`. Try see if you understand the question and answer there. But I could be wrong

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

I still get this error no matter what I do

Answer (score 0):

you can use static method of Uri class for parsing String to Uri like below:

```
final uri = Uri.parse("${ApiConstants.BASE_URL}trending/movie/day?api_key=${ApiConstants.API_KEY}");
```

Comment: final uri = Uri.parse("your_string");

So what should I write in your string section?